# Error in gathering many columns together using R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am beginner in R. I am looking to gathering some columns for plotting. I got this error "Error: Must supply a symbol or a string as argument". I  would be happy if you help me in how to fix this error.

```
library(readxl)

df =read_excel("a1-cereals.xls")

# Select columns 
df%>% select (c(-1,-2,-11,-14,15))->df1

# Filtering rows 

df_Type_C <- filter (df1, Type == "C")

head (df_Type_C)

df_Type_H <- filter (df1, Type == "H")

head (df_Type_C)

#Gathering columns to make a long table 

df_long <- gather (df1,Mes_Type,2:11)
```

This is a sample of the dataset I am working on:

[image]

Comment: Please provide your example data by using `dput`, not as an image. See [how to make MREs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest. I solved the problem right now df_long <- gather(df1,
                   key = "Element",
                   value = "value",
                   2:11)

Comment: ok, i will do for my next questions

Comment: In general, it's bad style to separate the brackets from the function names, try to keep it together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `gather` requires a name and value argument (supplied as strings, hence the error message. I imagine that supplying this would solve your problem. However, I strong encourage you to change from `gather` to the `pivot` arguments as `gather` has been retired. I think your code would work fine with `pivot`. Please see links below and good luck!

[Link1](https://blog.methodsconsultants.com/posts/data-pivoting-with-tidyr/)
[Link2](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html)